# Get list of all print servers in the domain in C#

Tags: c#, .net, network-printers

I'm working in a large environment writing a utility for a tech support team.  I need to provide a list of all the print servers in the domain and let them pick one.  Once they pick a print server, I will list all the print queues on that print server and have them select one.  I have found plenty of examples of how to pull the list of print queues from the print server, but no examples of how to get a list of print servers.

How can I get a list of all the print servers in a domain (C#)?

Comment: Did you find a solution, or did one of ours wirklich. Please share or vote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Management Namespace. 
Please refer to this thread:
[Is there a .NET way to enumerate all available network printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't see where that can help me get a list of print servers.  I can get all printers, but in our environment, that would be thousands.  I need to present a list of print servers and then once they select a print server, list the queues on that server.

Comment: Take a look at the System.Print.PrinterServer namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printserver.aspx. This has a GetPrintQueue method.

Comment: Exactly what I will use for the second half of the task.  I have that piece covered.  What I need is a way to get a list of all the print servers available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but you could look for all Computers in the network and check their name.

Like so:

```
// Reference System.DirectoryServices is needed

DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
    {
        if (computer.SchemaClassName == "Computer") {
            if (computer.Name.IndexOf("printer-prefix-or-so")==-1)
                Console.WriteLine(computer.Name);
        }                            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can do the following:

> Import-Module ActiveDirectory
>   Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(&(&(uncName=*)(objectCategory=printQueue))))" -properties *|Sort-Object -Unique -Property servername |select servername