# Get available print servers on network

Tags: .net, networking, network-printers

Is there a .NET api call to get all available print servers on a specific network domain. I've searched at length and haven't found one.

My goal is to retrieve all available printers for a print server, but I want to ensure the print server is up and running before trying to retrieve its mapped printers.

I have the call to get all of the printers for a print server, I just need to call to get available print servers on the network first.

Comment: System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters

Comment: That will get all locally installed printers on a given computer/server. I need all print servers on a given network.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. In that case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers. It has a link to http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=741&lngWId=10 where it is explained how you can do it.