# Fetch all printers available in the network - not just local printers

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, wmi, network-printers

I have been trying to find all printers in the network.But, I always ended up with printers which are already connected with my computer. When I try to add printers at
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers, I could find many more printers available in the network.

Please note that I don't have printer server. All printers are IP based.

I used following code:

```
WqlObjectQuery wQuery = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where " +
    "Local = FALSE");
ManagementObjectSearcher res = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wQuery);
if ((res.Get().Count > 0))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject printer in res.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(printer["PortName"] + " : " + printer["DriverName"] +
            " : " + printer["Status"]);
    }
}
else { Console.WriteLine("No printers found"); }
```

In the query, if I set local to true i get printers installed on my computer.

I also tried with similar questions here, but still no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I do believe this is the solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40569268/6513653)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMI cannot enumerate network printers, only can list the shared printers registered in the local machine. To this task you can use the  [WNetEnumResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385449%28VS.85%29.aspx), [WNetOpenEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385478%28VS.85%29.aspx) and  [WNetCloseEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385431%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinApi functions. Some time ago I wrote a sample of this using .Net 
Try this article [`Enumerating All Network resources using Delphi Prism`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/enumerating-all-network-resources-using-delphi-prism/), the code uses the `Oxygene` language but can be translated to C# easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot RRUZ. I had to spend some time to get this working. Of course with modifications as per my need. Finally I could.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, what you're looking for is outside of WMI's capabilities.

I know you dont have a print server, but if all the printers are at least connected to other machines, then a quick workaround might be to use [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run your printer finding script locally on all computers on your network (or maybe a login script).  You could simply make your printer finding script write to a network share, and then review the information once the execution completes.

Otherwise I would suggest using a network mapping tool like [ZenMap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) or a network monitoring tool like Spiceworks ( www.spiceworks.com) to fingerprint your devices.

Comment: Kyle, Thanks for your response. 1 up for you since you made me think more :)