# How do I show network printer in a browse dialog via C#?

Tags: c#, networking, printing, shared

basically what I want to do is allow the user of my software to browse the network for a printer shared on another computer or server, the problem is that printers do now show up in the File Selection dialog in c#, is there an alternative that shows printers? if this is not simple to do I may look into a drag and drop feature to get the path to the printer instead.

-Background-
This is for a program that can be scripted to do a lot of things for a computer when first installed at a customers location (such as branding for our company, updating windows, installing certain third party apps, mapping network drives, adding printers, changing some home page etc etc etc), I know i could manually enter in printer names for shared printers rather than browsing but the names are often long useless names that are hard to type.

UPDATE:
After some research and tinkering, I cannot drag and drop onto the form as it requires administrative privileges, there are still other, more convoluted options, such as selecting or entering the network computer name and manually getting shared printers, but allowing them to select them via an explorer would be nice.

Comment: A "file selection dialog" is an unlikely place to find a printer back.  Try PrintDialog.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I'm attempting to select printers which are not currently installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below links...

[Is there a .NET way to enumerate all available network printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers)

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-get-list-of-Local-and-Network-Printers-1495.php

Comment: Ended up using something like this to achieve an end result, the user now enters the name of the computer hosting the shared printer and it then lists all shared printers on that computer and they can select from those. Not quite what I wanted but it's a workable solution for now.