# List available network printers (non-installed as well)

Tags: c#, list, printers

Meaning i am able to enum all printers (network and local) but ONLY if they are installed on my PC

However i want to be able to list those that are not installed and can be seen by using (windows built-in) ADD PRINTER dialog.

Is it even possible as i couldn't find anything useful browsing various forums/boards including stackexchange.

Meaning i tried the built-in .NET classes and WMI as well (`SELECT * from Win32_Printer`) but obviously they list only the installed printers.

Thank you so much in advance

EDIT: please notice that suggested answer does not address non-installed printers but rather only installed ones. I am already able to list those. Thx

Comment: You may want to be more explicit in which "Suggested answer" you are talking about.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers[/link]

Comment: Hi, I do believe this is the solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40569268/6513653)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is anything in .NET that can do this, you will need to make a native call. [Here is the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385341(v=vs.85).aspx) about how to enumerate network resources, what you will need to do is P/Invoke the `WNetEnumResource` function to get [`NETRESOURCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385353(v=vs.85).aspx) objects back.

You are looking for objects that have a `dwType` of `RESOURCETYPE_PRINT`, when you find them you check `lpRemoteName` to get the name of the printer.

Here is a link to [a example snippet](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=741&lngWId=10) implementing its use (Even though the URL states it is VB the code is in C#). I would post it here but the note on the page expressly does not allow copying and pasting of the script without permission of the author.

Comment: thank you so much about this... it looks very promising and i am about to test the suggested code. Will keep you updated. Thank you again

Comment: Hmm i guess i cannot compile that code. I get some errors (Method must have a return type)  on the line: //now call the function passing a null
WNETOE(null);

Comment: i was able to compile the project. Worked fine though i am not quite sure how to list only the printers. I'll keep analyzing the code. Thx

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. It's much appreciated. Meaning i a able to check the type but they all return RESOURCETYPE_ANY ... though i can see the non-installed printer via "Add Printer" dialog. Any ideas?