# How to check if printer is in network?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am using this code to check if my printer is in the network. When I hit the Print button the first time, it gives me not connected status. And when I hit it for the second time it prints successfully. But my printer is always in the network.

```
public bool IsPrinterReady(string PrinterName)
{
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Printer");

    string strPrinter = string.Empty;
    foreach(ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
    {
        strPrinter = printer["Name"].ToString();
        if(strPrinter.ToLower() == PrinterName.ToLower())
           return printer["PrinterStatus"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("3");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please note that I always get the value as true for my following if statement

```
if(strPrinter.ToLower() == PrinterName.ToLower())
```

I just get varied values from

```
printer["PrinterStatus"].ToString()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers

Comment: @Yanshof I get the network printer always but for some reason I get the value for printer["PrinterStatus"] as 4 the first time and the second time I get 3 which is the value I am looking for.